# Static Method implementation in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, static

I am confused with `Static` implementation in VB.NET. In C#, we can create Static class and static methods to write utility methods for our application.

Now, VB.NET lets us create `Module` in place of static class. If we create a method in the module, by default it becomes static. But in my application, I have written the below code:

```vb
Public Class Utility
    Public Shared Function GetValue() As String
       // My code
    End Function
End Class
```

By writing the code, I am able to access the utility method as `Utility.GetValue()`. As this is not a static class, I am supposed to instantiate an object of it. But this method is available for both the class and objects of `Utility`

Now my questions are:

1. Is the implementation I have done may violate any of the features of static class that module provide?
2. What will be difference between this and implementing a module instead?
3. If I create a module instead, will the scope of that will be same as this class? I want to access the method throughout the project as well as other projects where this one is referenced.

I tried consulting multiple articles, but nowhere found this exact answers. Please help.

Comment: Behind the scenes, a Public function in a Module is converted to a Shared function of a Class; they are the same thing.  Even though Utility can be instantiated, you **cannot** access GetValue() through an instance of Utility; you'd still have to use `Utility.GetValue()`.

Comment: The main difference is that with a Class you could also have non-shared members in Utility (you can't access those non-shared elements from the shared ones though).  But with respect to **only** the Shared members, it will be the same as using a Module.

Comment: I am able to access the `GetValue()` method for object instances as well. That's where my confusion arises. @Idle_Mind

Comment: Clarification, you'll get a **warning** that you shouldn't be accessing the shared member thru an instance (depending on how you've configured warnings/errors in visual studio, it may be treated as an **error**).  In reality, you're not really accessing the shared member thru an instance as it is "fixed" automatically for you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A VB.NET module *is* a static class. The compiler handles this for you. Every method and property on it is `static` (`Shared`).

A class with a static (Shared) member on it is exactly that: a class with a static (Shared) member. You don't have to create an instance of it to access the static (Shared) method, but you do to get to any of its instance members.

You can also define a `Sub New()` in a module, and it becomes the static constructor for the module. The first time you try to invoke a member on the module, the static constructor will be invoked to initialize the static class.

Answer (score 14):

Use 'shared' to make a class sub or function 'static' (in the C# sense).
In VB, shared is like a synonym for static, in this context.